# How to get the string in the JTextPane around the caret?

Tags: java, jtextpane

For example, there is a JTextPane which has some text like "123456abcd789", and the caret is now between the '7'.

See this for explanation:
"123456abcd|789". Here the '|' represents the caret.

And now I want to get the longest string before the caret which includes only a-z. Here it would be "abcd".

But if I use the method jtextpane.getCaretPosition(), I'll get an integer 11.(because there are 10 ascii chars and a picture before the caret). It isn't the integer I wanted. Maybe I can count the number of chars of the **img**s, but it's still troublesome, and easy for bugs to appear.

So how to get the correct string?

### EXAMPLE

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello, everybody!!<br>
            <img src="xx.jpg">
        </p>
        <p>
            Hello, everybody|!!<br>   //The caret is here, at the left of '!'
            <img src="xx.jpg">
        </p>
        <p>
            Hello, everybody!!<br>
            <img src="xx.jpg">
        </p>
    </body>
<html>
```

In the example above, the caret is now in the second sentence.

And what I want to do is to replace the "everybody" just before the caret into "everyone"(the rest "everybody" remain itself). But if I use getCaretPosition() I won't get the correct index of the '!' in the HTML text.

So what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to count the number of characters from A to Z and a to z.

This would be the correct expression: `([a-zA-Z]+)`

You can try more combinations using [this online regex tool.](https://regex101.com/)

---

**EDIT**

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/Cv98Sv/1) is the regex that you can use.

Comment: Uh, I'm not asking how to find the number of characters /[a-z]+/. In fact, when I use the method jtextpane.getText(), I'll get something like this:"<html><head></head><body><p>123456<img src='xxx.jpg'>abcd789</p></body></html>", and what I want to do is to get the index of '7' in this string. As you know, there may not be only one '7' in the string...

Comment: You can parse the string using a correct regex ([here](https://regex101.com/r/Cv98Sv/1) is an example with your string: "<html><head></head><body><p>123456<img src='xxx.jpg'>abcd789</p></body></html>") and then extract the group you want to check.

Comment: Why would you use an HTMLDocument (JTextPane with html content) if you'd rather to manipulate the plain text ? Anyway, if you're sure about your choice, use Jsoup to manipulate the resulting html. The text() method will become very handy.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers! But what I want to do is to find the position of the caret. Oh, I will edit my question to make it more clear. By the way, when I was using HTMLDocument, I found some words in my language becomes empty squares(although I had set the content type "text/html;charset=utf-8", the problem remained there). That's the reason why I don't use it...Do you have any ideas about that? Anyway thank you very much!!

Comment: Finally I used the regex to clear all the tags and /\n */ in the html, wrote a method to read the visual characters in the html in order to find the position corresponding to the caret and get satisfying result. Anyway thank you!